# case statement in window functions

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to put indicators to each unique bundle (subs_key, ban_key) in each of the two months
I get null values everywhere (i.e. case statement does not work)
Can you help me what to find the error?

```
select 
        s.subs_key ||s.ban_key,
        s.TIME_KEY,  
        s.PRICE_PLAN_CHANGE_DATE,  
        s. active_group,
        (case
            when s.time_key =  to_date('01.05.21','dd.mm.yy') and  s. active_group  = '1' and s.time_key = to_date ('01.06.21', 'dd.mm.yy') and s. active_group  = '0' then 'out paid migr'
            when s.time_key =  to_date('01.05.21','dd.mm.yy') and  s. active_group  = '0' and s.time_key =to_date ('01.06.21', 'dd.mm.yy') and s. active_group  = '1' then 'in paid migr'
            when s.time_key = to_date('01.05.21','dd.mm.yy') and  s. active_group  = '1' and s.time_key =to_date ('01.06.21', 'dd.mm.yy') and s. active_group  = '1' then 'core base'
            end as migration_status) over (partition by s.subs_key ||s.ban_key order by s.time_key )
```

Comment: you can start with changing the date syntax such as `date'2021-05-01` rather than `to_date('01.05.21','dd.mm.yy')`, and `active_group='1'` rather than `active_group=1` presuming `active_key` has a date and `active_group` has a numeric(most probably an integer) type

Comment: Rather than only posting your trial, May you please post your sample data and expected result? Also, where is your window function? I am not able to see any analytical function here?

Comment: To expand on the above, a window function would be `<function>(<parameters>) OVER (<window>)`  Such as `MIN(<CASE Expression>) OVER (partition by s.subs_key, s.ban_key order by s.time_key)`.  You're missing the `MIN`, or whichever function you want to apply to the window.

Comment: Also, please read the following link about including enough information and example data to make a useful question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How  s.time_key  and s.active_group can be equal different values at the same time `when s.time_key =  to_date('01.05.21','dd.mm.yy') and  s. active_group  = '1' and s.time_key = to_date ('01.06.21', 'dd.mm.yy') and s. active_group  = '0' then 'out paid migr'`

Answer (score 0):

First, your `case` expression has an `over` clause.  That is incorrect syntax.  You need an appropriate analytic function.

Second, use a `date` constant.  Assuming the time key has not components.

Third, a `time_key` cannot have two values at the same time, yet you are comparing the `time_key` to two values.

It is unclear what you want to do, because you have not provided sample data, desired results, or an explanation of what the code should be doing.  However, the code you have in the question is syntactically and logically incorrect, so it should only produce an error.